# Django - How to Get current object in queryset?

Tags: python, django

Views.py

```
class ProfileView(UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = "profile/profile_view.html"
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'profile'

def test_func(self):
    x = self.request.user.full_name
    print (x)
    y = ''
    if x == y:
        raise Http404("Profile Inactive")
    else:
        return True
```

Question - If the `full_name` of the user is empty i want to display `Profile Inactive` error but i am not able to print the `full_name`. I don't want to print the `full_name` of the logged in user but the user's page. the user's page is defined by slug `localhost:8000/slug`.

Comment: Is there an attribute called full name? If not you might have to query for first name and last name explicitly

Comment: i am using Custom User Model and i have a field called `full_name`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, or how the body of your question relates to the title. What current object? What irrelevant data?

Comment: i have updated the question.

Comment: @Rahul, I think you are looking for `self.get_object()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `self.get_object()` to get the object based on the lookup field.

Answer (score 0):

`x = self.get_object().full_name`

Worked! thanks!